# Spring Test if class resolved it's Autowired dependencies

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a this class

```
@Component("A")
public class A {
    private B b;

    @Autowired
    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

and another class

```
@Component("B")
public class B {

    public B() {

    }
}
```

Now I've written this test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class ConstructorAutowiredTest {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public B getBBean() {
            B b = new B();
            return b;
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private B b;


    @Test
    public void isDependencyResolved() {
        assertNotNull(b);
    }
}
```

It works as well. But is there any way to test whether this `B` bean was automatically injected in `A`. I'm trying to so something like this but obviously it's not working.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class ConstructorAutowiredTest {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public B getBBean() {
            B b = new B();
            return b;
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private A a;

    @Autowired
    private B b;


    @Test
    public void isDependencyResolved() {
        assertNotNull(b);
        assertNotNull(a);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.abc.ConstructorAutowiredTest': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'a'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'com.abc.A' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: Well, clearly that test is failing because the dependency is not being resolved, at least you now know it. What is your question, exactly?

Comment: I fail to see what you want to test here. You're just testing your test-secific configuration. What's the point?

Comment: @Pablo I know. But I'm not able to figure it out that how to specify something like `@ComponentScan("com.abc")` here.

Comment: @JBNizet the original application is somewhat different. I want to check here whether all dependencies are resolved automatically or not.

Comment: I think I understand that. But what will this test say about your actual, production code, since the actual, production code doesn't use tha configuration used by your test? You're testing that your test is configured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could have added to your configuration a component scan which uploads your @Component("A")

like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("some.package")
static class ContextConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public B getBBean() {
        B b = new B();
        return b;
    }
}
```

This would resolve your exception, and then you could assert your Bean A if it has B inserted.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand your question, I think you are using JUnit to test something that is not a unit test but something closer to an integration test, which is out of the scope of JUnit.

JUnit will always assume that you have initialized properly the class to be tested, dependency resolutions aren't its responsability.

And, as you have seen, Spring won't event let that test  start if the dependencies are not solved